# Show the Key(letter) pressed in a div using javascript not jquery

Tags: javascript

I need to write a javascript code for a 5 letter word game that will detect when a Key(letter) is pressed to show in a div.  Each letter of the word should display in its own div. If the player enters a letter and it's one of the letters in the word it should show up in one of the 5 divs if not then it should show in a another set of divs (7), player gets 7 guesses.  I just need this part to get me started on the rest of the project.

thanks in advance,
greatfulOne

Comment: Use a keydown, keyup, or keypress listener. Did you try to implement this yourself yet?

Answer (score 1):

[QuirksMode has an awesome page on detecting keystrokes.](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html).

To summarize, you'll want to either target the `keydown` or `keyup` event, and check for the `keyCode` property of the event object that is generated.

Some of the more complicated keys have cross-browser difficulties, but you should be okay if you're sticking with a-z. (Could be wrong, but it looks like "a" has a `keyCode` of 65, "z" has 90, and the other letters fill in.)